# Basic coffin positioning

Tags: xcoffins

Recipient address is shifted to the right in French letters. I'm adding an indication that it will be sent by email (`(via ...@...fr)`) just below the formal address, and centered. I have somewhat achieved the desired result using two calls to `makebox`. I'm looking to experiment with `xcoffins`. Could someone suggest a way to complete it to resemble the benchmark case?

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy tex

\NewCoffin\CoffTop
\NewCoffin\CoffBot

%%%%%%%%%   set figures width/height  plus height of text area
\newlength{\maxwidthT}
\setlength{\maxwidthT}{\widthof{XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXX}}
\newlength{\maxwidthB}
\setlength{\maxwidthB}{\widthof{(via \texttt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr})}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAddressTop}{}
{\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0mm}}l@{\extracolsep{0mm}}}
   XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXX\\
   XXXXXXX / XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX\\
   XXXXXX XX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXX\\
   XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX
 \end{tabular}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAddressBot}{}
{\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0mm}}c@{\extracolsep{0mm}}}
   \multicolumn{1}{l}{(via \texttt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr})}
 \end{tabular}}
          
\begin{document}

% Approach 1)
\makebox[0.9\textwidth][r]
{ \frame{\MyAddressTop} }\par
\makebox[0.96\textwidth][r]
{  \frame{\MyAddressBot} }

\vspace{2em}
 
% Approach 2)
\SetVerticalCoffin\CoffTop{\maxwidthT}{\frame{\MyAddressTop}}
\SetVerticalCoffin\CoffBot{\maxwidthT}{\frame{\MyAddressBot}}
\JoinCoffins*\CoffTop[hc,b]\CoffBot[hc,t]

%\TypesetCoffin⟨coffin⟩[⟨pole1⟩,⟨pole2⟩](⟨x-offset⟩,⟨y-offset⟩)

\TypesetCoffin\CoffTop

\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not tied to the use of coffins, `stackengine` offers a trivial solution in the form of `\stackunder[\fboxrule]{\frame{\MyAddressTop}}{\frame{\MyAddressBot}}`.  Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{stackengine}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAddressTop}{}
{\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0mm}}l@{\extracolsep{0mm}}}
   XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XX XXXXX\\
   XXXXXXX / XXXXXXXXXXX XXXXX\\
   XXXXXX XX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXX\\
   XXXXX XXXXX XXXXX XX
 \end{tabular}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyAddressBot}{}
{\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{0mm}}c@{\extracolsep{0mm}}}
   \multicolumn{1}{l}{(via \texttt{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.fr})}
 \end{tabular}}
          
\begin{document}
\stackunder[\fboxrule]{\frame{\MyAddressTop}}{\frame{\MyAddressBot}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Were you to `\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}` in advance of the stack, the resulting stack would be left-aligned.  Likewise `r` for right-alignment.

Comment: Thx, likely the way to go for such a narrow problem. Still, I'd like to see the solution with coffins.